# Tizen tv web app jquery.min.js not found error

Tags: javascript, web-applications, tizen, tizen-tv

I have downloaded Tizen IDE 2.4 and tv emulator.
I created a project using new project -> online samples -> System Info
I ran the app using run as ->Tizen web simulator application (samsung TV) and the emulator launched.
But in the web inspector tool I can see the following errors:

`GET file:///C:/Users/abhilashk/TizenTV_workspace/SystemInfo/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw-libs.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:12`

`GET file:///C:/Users/abhilashk/TizenTV_workspace/SystemInfo/tizen-web-ui-fw/latest/js/tizen-web-ui-fw.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I checked and these files are not present there.
I was expecting the files to be downloaded when I created the project. I downloaded the project from online samples.

I am new to web apps and this is my first project. So please guide me. 
I can't find any helpful tutorials to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want launch app to Emulator (NOT SIMULATOR) use `rus as -> Tizen Web Application` and set target to Emulator.
Maybe IDE can choose target during emulators or real devices.

Comment: In emulator also the app is not running.

Comment: I tried simulator to use the web inspector. thats when i realised that the js libraries are not getting loaded. i want to know how can i fix the above errors ?\